# Is creating two FILEs for the same file descriptor well-defined?

Tags: c, posix, language-lawyer, file-descriptor, stdio

POSIX specifies an [fdopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html) function that creates a `FILE` for a file descriptor. POSIX also specifies a [fileno](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fileno.html) function that returns the file descriptor for a `FILE`. Together, these two could be used to create a second `FILE` accessing the same underlying file descriptor as an existing file:

```
FILE *secondfile(FILE *f, const char *mode)
{
    int fd = fileno(f);

    return fd >= 0 ? fdopen(fd, mode) : NULL;
}
```

Is this a well-defined operation under POSIX? What happens when I access both the original `FILE` and the second `FILE` I made for the same file descriptor? Is the interaction specified? If yes, how?

Historically, Unices used a fixed table of `FILE` structures for the 20 files you could open. Calling `fdopen()` on a file descriptor that has already been associated with a `FILE` would thus corrupt the existing file and yield undefined behaviour. I am not sure if such an implementation of `stdio` is still allowed by POSIX, which is why I am asking this question.

Comment: I cannot imagine that this would work.

Comment: I would suspect it's *not* well-defined, as the results of IO operations would depend on the interaction of the data in the `FILE` structure with the (shared) offset of the underlying file descriptor.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Neither could I, but I haven't found language in POSIX concerning this scenario and other language seems to suggest that it is well-defined, which is why I am asking.

Comment: Althought the documentation calls the result of `fileno` _file descriptor_, it is more of a handle. However, as the `FILE` structure also might include buffering, etc. of the libc, you will likely be busted if you use two distinct `FILE`s for the same handle. The handle is likely more for low-level access through the direct system calls, bypassing the stdlib functions. Either way, it is not clear why you actually would want to do that. If you need multiple access position into the file, you might better mmap them or write your own layer on top of the stdlib.

Comment: @Olaf POSIX specifies how file-descriptor based IO is supposed to interact with `stdio`, it's not unlikely that the interaction between different `FILE` structures for the same file descriptor is also defined.

Comment: It is defined by POSIX (§2.5.1 [Interaction of File Descriptors and Standard I/O Streams](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_01)), but using them together entails certain requirements.

Comment: Like Micheal pointed out, the requirements are stated there. Basically, the answer is it's well-defined to have multiple file descriptors or file pointers or a combinations of them thereof (for the same file -- as in the example), as long those requirements are met by the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX [explicitly permits](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05) multiple "handles" to be associated simultaneously with the same underlying "open file description", where handles can be either file descriptors or streams.  Although it does not specifically address multiple streams opened via `fdopen()` on the same file descriptor, I see no reason to suppose that these would be subject to more or different requirements than any two streams associated with the same open file description are generally subject to.

POSIX defines [constraints on how two handles on the same open file description may be used](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_01) in order to avoid undefined behavior.  It is relevant here that those constraints are few indeed for handles that are file descriptors; almost all of them apply to streams, and they are organized mainly around conditions related to buffering.  The exceptions are related to positioning.

If you use your streams in a manner consistent with those constraints -- mostly, but not exclusively, by ensuring that output is not buffered unwritten in one stream when you switch to using the other -- you can expect the stream I/O functions to behave as documented.  Otherwise, the behavior is explicitly undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Given a typical Unix implementation, with a FILE data structure containing a file descriptor to read from, and a buffer for, eh, buffering, and if you know the size of the buffer, and the policy for filling it (when the data is needed, not immediately when the buffer is empty), I would say that you *can* determine what will happen. But I don't know what the POSIX standard says, and I *do* know that it will be a difficult thing to use in a program. ("Ok, so I've read the first 4096 bytes from the file on disk into *this* FILE, and the next 4096 bytes into *that* FILE, and the third 4096-byte chunk from the file will be read into the FILE that reaches the end of its buffer first and needs to read more...")

(I've never done anything like this deliberately, but I seem to remember such symptoms from debugging code that got FILEs and file descriptors mixed up.)

My *guess* would be that POSIX doesn't specify this well enough that it will be guaranteed to work. For example, does POSIX specify when a buffer inside a FILE will be filled by reading from the file descriptor? When empty, when empty *and* more data is needed, or either of these, depending on something? Depending on choice there, data from the file descriptor will show up in different FILEs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would prefer an answer based on what the standard says instead of what a typical UNIX does. There are quite atypical Unices (e.g. Windows) and seemingly obvious assumptions may not hold on these.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Yes, someone with more knowledge of the POSIX standard will have to give a more authoritative answer.